# Using a shared external package for proto files?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

We have a few projects that depend on shared types to communicate. The teams have decided to use a shared package with those types, and would like to use protocol buffers for this implementation. If it matters, the language is Go, and all of these projects are not public.

How can we use protocol buffer types not defined within our project? I can't seem to find a way to share completely external types amongst applications. Everything I read tends to explain how to use sub-package `.proto` files but not types defined by another developer/team in another project within your project.

Comment: A non Go based solution would be to use git submodules to clone those `.proto` files to your project and update it regularly with git. This is the trivial sub-package approach.

Comment: Go does not restrict code to be in a single repository. You use import paths and `go get` to use code from any repositories. Putting proto files in a different repository is not special in this regard. Just commit the generated Go files into the proto's repository, and import that path in your Go project where you want to use it. There are tricks to make `go get` work with private repos (google it), or just manually clone the repository into your Go workspace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `protoc` and specify the include path, as example:

```
protoc -I/usr/local/include -I. \
-I${GOPATH}/src \
-I${GOPATH}/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis \
--go_out=$DST_DIR \ 
my-proto.proto
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Create a repository for your new package (auto generated from the `.proto` files). Ie:

```
protoc --go_out=$GOPATH/your/git/repo /path/to/your/schema.proto
```

Make sure you `git push` the repo.

Then on the external projects that need to use it, just include:

```
import "your/git/repo/schema/yourStruct"
```